# Index data from Data Providers in Sitecore 7

Tags: lucene, sitecore, sitecore7

I have a data provider that integrates content into a Sitecore 7 solution. How can I get indexing working for the data provided? At the moment none of the content provided by the data providers is indexed. Is there a way to add some kind of indexer for this content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that this was handled OOTB it just took a while to index all the data.

There is good documentation here:
http://sdn.sitecore.net/Developer/Integrating%20External%20Data%20Sources.aspx
http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%207/Sitecore%20Search%20and%20Indexing%20Guide.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As per default if the data that you imported into Sitecore is published to the web database, for all of those files the index will be updated. To be able to search on custom fields, you should adjust the default search configuration to make the indexer pickup the fields. For more information I would like to redirect you to the Sitecore documentation here:

http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%207/Developers%20Guide%20to%20Item%20Buckets%20and%20Search.aspx